# Haskell - built in tuple with Ord defined to compare by first element only?

Tags: haskell

I am relatively new to Haskell, so hopefully this is not a dumb question. I'm looking for a common / well known type that essentially acts a tuple, but has `Ord` defined such that it only compares by the first element.

I can define this myself as such:

```hs
data RankedItem a = RankedItem Double a deriving (Show)

instance Eq (RankedItem a) where
  (RankedItem lkey _) == (RankedItem rkey _) = lkey == rkey

instance Ord (RankedItem a) where
  (RankedItem lkey _) `compare` (RankedItem rkey _) = compare lkey rkey
```

Is there a built in type or a commonly used third party container that achieves this?

Comment: Once we get dependent types, we can derive this with `deriving (Eq, Ord, Hashable, ..) via On key` where `key (RankedItem k _) = k`. I am looking forward to this, but not yet possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such a type exists. It's the [`Arg` type defined in Data.Semigroup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Arg). Its `Eq` and `Ord` instances only compare based off the first element, and it has various other instances (like `Functor`) that act off the second element.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I need.